# Parsing the file name from list of url links

Tags: python, parsing, hyperlink, filenames

Ok so I am using a script that is downloading a files from urls listed in a urls.txt.

```
import urllib.request

with open("urls.txt", "r") as file:
    linkList = file.readlines()
for link in linkList:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(link)
```

Unfortunately they are saved as temporary files due to lack of second argument in my urllib.request.urlretrieve function. As there are thousand of links in my text file naming them separately is not an option. The thing is that the name of the file is contained in those links, i.e.  /DocumentXML2XLSDownload.vm?firsttime=true&repengback=true&d‌​ocumentId=XXXXXX&xsl‌​FileName=rher2xml.xs‌​l&outputFileName=XXX‌​X_2017_06_25_4.xls where the name of the file comes after outputFileName=

Is there an easy way to parse the file names and then use them in  urllib.request.urlretrieve function as secondary argument? I was thinking of extracting those names in excel and placing them in another text file that would be read in similar fashion as urls.txt but I'm not sure how to implement it in Python. Or is there a way to make it exclusively in python without using excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse the link on the go.

Example using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

```
import re

with open("urls.txt", "r") as file:
    linkList = file.readlines()
for link in linkList:
    regexp = '((?<=\?outputFileName=)|(?<=\&outputFileName=))[^&]+'
    match = re.search(regexp, link.rstrip())

    if match is None:
        # Make the user aware that something went wrong, e.g. raise exception
        # and/or just print something
        print("WARNING: Couldn't find file name in link [" + link + "]. Skipping...")
    else:
        file_name = match.group(0)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, file_name)
```

Comment: It seems like this method returns file_name <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(156, 178), match='XXXX_2017_06_25_4.xls\n'> as I get TypeError: invalid file:

Comment: @Seidhe My bad, it should work now. Could you try again?

Comment: It seems like there should be closing parenthesis in the print. Other than that I get this kind of error:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\My Documents\PYTHON\download.py", line 8, in <module>
    file_name = re.search(regexp, link).group(0)
  File "F:\TOO\Team\Software\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 173, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "F:\TOO\Team\Software\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 293, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)

sre_constants.error: unterminated character set at position 47

Comment: it works after the edit! Thank you very much. I've also tried different route as I still can not fathom how regexp works and I need some more time to understand it. :)
file_names_list = []
for element in linkList:
    file_names_list.append(element.strip()[-21:])
for link, file_name in zip(linkList, file_names_list):
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, file_name) As the name of file always has a constant number of letters this works as well. I'll upvote as soon I am able to. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Seidhe By the way, I recommend resources such as https://regex101.com when learning regular expressions, I use that particular site all the time when creating my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use urlparse and parse_qs to get the query string

> ```
> from urlparse import urlparse,parse_qs
> parse = urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html?name=Python&version=2')
> print(parse_qs(parse.query)['name'][0]) # prints Python
> ```

Comment: As I understand it creates a dictionary of strings that come after name= and before &? As I'm completely new to the Python could you please show me how it should look in my code?

Comment: urlparse query will return the query string on that we are splitting by & and creating dict which means http://www.test.com/print?name=test&x=12345&y=12345678 will create dictionary as 

`{'name':'test','x':'12345','y':'12345678'}`

Comment: Please don't re-invent the stdlib. The `urlparse` module also includes the `parse_qs` method for parsing query strings and returning a dict. Your dict comprehension would simplify to `query_param_dict = parse_qs(parse.query)`.